# View.getMeasuredWidth() return different values at different time

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a problem with View.getMeasuredWidth(),
when i call it first time, it return me the value 1243, then i add some childs to this view,

when activity is visible on screen and i touch any child, i have override onTouchEvent() function and i log the values of view.getMeasuredWidth() and it returns different values. now here it returns 621.

Why is View.getMeasuredWidth() returning different values at different time.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more specific? When are you calling `getMeasuredWidth()`? Are you trying to get the *measured* width, or the *actual* width?

Comment: I think it is returning the width of view you are touching,2nd time u touched a child thats y 621

Comment: @Karakuri i am trying to get measuredwidth(), because actual width of layout is returning 0 right now.

Comment: @Arju no child have 621 width, because i have tried it by assigning fixed width to each child. the return values was still 621.

Comment: getWidth() will return zero until the the first layout occurs. There are ways to get that.